# Delete row when values match in 2 columns apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to figure out why my function upon iterating through the loop doesn't increment to the next value in the range of column values. I will share for reference (below). The function is intended to pass the sheet and search key to find the values in two cols in a staging and prod sheet and return the rowNum that matches the search key in both sheets. Then delete the corresponding row. Please see the logs and execution transcript (following code)

```
function findInColumn(sheet, data) 
{
  if(sheet.getName() == "Data" || sheet.getName() == "Info")
  {

    var column = sheet.getRange("D" + ":" + "D");  // like A:A

    var values = column.getValues(); 
    var row = 0;

    while ( values[row] && values[row][0] != data ) {
      row++;
    }

    if (values[row][0] == data) 
      return row+1;
    else 
      return -1;
  }
  else if(sheet.getName() == "AdData" || sheet.getName() == "AdInfo")
  {
    var columnID = sheet.getRange("C" + ":" + "C"),
        columnEmail = sheet.getRange("I"+ ":" + "I");  // like A:A

    var valuesID = [columnID.getValues()],
        valuesEmail = [columnEmail.getValues()]; 

    for(var row = 0;row<valuesID.length;row++)
    {
        if(valuesID[row][0] == data)
        {
          return Logger.log(row+1);
        }
        else if(valuesEmail[row][0] == data)
        {
          return Logger.log(row+1);
        }
        else
        {
         Logger.log("ID " + valuesID[row][0] + "\nEmail " + valuesEmail[row][0] + "\n");
         continue; 
        }
    }
    Logger.log("No matching ID AND Email were found");
  }
  else
  {
    return Logger.log("No sheet was found with that name.");
  }
}
```

**Execution Transcripts:**

> [18-11-07 11:17:00:183 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0
>   seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:183 PST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:183 PST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:183 PST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:183 PST] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:183 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0
>   seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:190 PST] Starting execution
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:194 PST] Logger.log([Success! Named Values Site
>   Admin Opt:  Remove Site Admin, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:195 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0
>   seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:304 PST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Admin Data])
>   [0.109  seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:305 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0
>   seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:305 PST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Admin Info])
>   [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:306 PST] Logger.log([123 test@test.com , []]) [0
>   seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:306 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:306 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:306 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:306 PST] Sheet.getRange([C:C]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:307 PST] Sheet.getRange([I:I]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:562 PST] Range.getValues() [0.255 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:740 PST] Range.getValues() [0.176 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:741 PST] Logger.log([ID Site ID Email Admin Email ,
>   []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:741 PST] Logger.log([No matching SiteID AND Admin
>   Email were found, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:742 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:742 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:742 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:742 PST] Sheet.getRange([C:C]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:00:743 PST] Sheet.getRange([I:I]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:001 PST] Range.getValues() [0.257 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:002 PST] Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:004 PST] Logger.log([ID Site ID Email Admin Email ,
>   []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:004 PST] Logger.log([No matching SiteID AND Admin
>   Email were found, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:004 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:004 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:004 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:005 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:005 PST] Sheet.getRange([C:C]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:006 PST] Sheet.getRange([I:I]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:255 PST] Range.getValues() [0.248 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:556 PST] Range.getValues() [0.3 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:557 PST] Logger.log([ID Site ID Email Admin Email ,
>   []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:558 PST] Logger.log([No matching SiteID AND Admin
>   Email were found, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:558 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:558 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:558 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:558 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:558 PST] Sheet.getRange([C:C]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:559 PST] Sheet.getRange([I:I]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:01:817 PST] Range.getValues() [0.257 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:035 PST] Range.getValues() [0.217 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:036 PST] Logger.log([ID Site ID Email Admin Email ,
>   []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:037 PST] Logger.log([No matching SiteID AND Admin
>   Email were found, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:037 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:037 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:037 PST] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:038 PST] Sheet.getRange([C:C]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:038 PST] Sheet.getRange([I:I]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:316 PST] Range.getValues() [0.278 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:318 PST] Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:320 PST] Logger.log([ID Site ID Email Admin Email ,
>   []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:320 PST] Logger.log([No matching SiteID AND Admin
>   Email were found, []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [18-11-07 11:17:02:324 PST] Execution failed: Cannot find method
>   deleteRow((class)). (line 113, file "macros") [2.127 seconds total
>   runtime]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
var valuesID = [columnID.getValues()],
valuesEmail = [columnEmail.getValues()];
```

by

```
var valuesID = columnID.getValues(),
valuesEmail = columnEmail.getValues();
```

here you are trying to increment a 3D array like it was a 2D array. `getValues` already returns a 2D array.

**REFERENCES**

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Comment: Thank you so much that did it! Only now I've added a few rows from 931 to 943 (manually for testing purposed of the deleteRow()) and the function is only iterating to 931 still????

Comment: @MikalDChavez not sure how to solve this issue but if you want to delete rows do it backward. from 943 to 931.

Comment: I've used .reverse() and now it's only iterating through the rows I've added and returning the wrong row number to pass to deleteRow(). This could be a data type error...????

Comment: @MikalDChavez please create a new post with full code I'll be happy to help

Comment: Just confirmed I was comparing a string to int. Thank you for all your help